# Segmentation fault using devtoolset-10 with boost 1.73 static libraries complied with gcc 7.5.0

Tags: boost, g++, static-libraries, rhel, devtoolset

I have boost 1.73 static libraries (.a) and RHEL devtoolset-10 installed,I do the following steps

```
scl enable devtoolset-10 bash
```

Check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to

> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib:/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib64/dyninst:/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/dyninst:/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib

I set the CXX and CC to /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/bin/g++ and /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/bin/gcc respectively

This is snippet of my makefile

```
LPATH  := -L/home/boost/lib/linux.2_6.x86_64 \
      -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/bin/ \
      -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10 \
      -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib64

LFLAG  := -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -l:libstdc++.a -l:libgcc.a -static 
    
.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)
    
$(EXE): $(BUILTOBJ)
    $(CXX) -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS -Xlinker -Map=rhel.map $(LPATH) -o $@ $(BUILTOBJ) $(LFLAG) 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CXX) -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS $(INCLUDES) -c  $< -o $@   

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c 
      mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Segmentation fault occurs at these three places..I got the boost functions that throw error ,these are

> boost::filesystem::path src(sourcepath);

```
src.filename()
for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator file(src); file!=boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++file)
boost::filesystem::remove_all(sourcepath);
```

Also a snippet on my rhel.map file

> (boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&))
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(bad_alloc.o)
> /home/boost/lib/linux.2_6.x86_64/libboost_filesystem.a(directory.o) (typeinfo for std::bad_alloc)
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(class_type_info.o)
> obj/Action.o (vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info)
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(del_op.o)                      /home/boost/lib/linux.2_6.x86_64/libboost_filesystem.a(exception.o) (operator delete(void*))
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(del_ops.o)
> obj/Action.o (operator delete(void*, unsigned long))
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(del_opv.o)
> obj/CZip.o (operator delete)
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(dyncast.o)
> obj/Action.o (__dynamic_cast)
> /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/libstdc++.a(eh_alloc.o)
> obj/Action.o (__cxa_allocate_exception)

Also if I use the -g flag I get this and similar DWARF debug error

> DWARF error: could not find variable specification at offset 23b28

The code works fine in ubuntu which has gcc 9.3.1 but in rhel-7 with devtoolset it gives segmentation fault(core dumped)

Is there some error with my linking?